# How can I sortBy() multiple values in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

It appears that Laravel doesn't offer a way to sort by multiple conditions.  In my instance I want to sort a collection by a value I call sort_order in ascending order, then a date in descending order.

`$item->sortBy('sort_order')->sortByDesc('date');`

This will sort by the first condition, then overwrite the prior sortBy with the second one.

From what I've read in the [laravel](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11) doesn't support this.  Has anyone else faced this issue and if so, how did you solve for it?

I'm using Laravel 5.6.

Comment: updated answer you may try see if it works.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11 Here's some reference as it looks like your questions

Answer (score 3):

I did solved this by grouping them up and sort again then collapse:

```
$items->sortBy('sort_order')
      ->groupBy('sort_order')
      ->map(function ($subSet) {
          return $subSet->sortByDesc('date');
      })->collapse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
$collection->sortBy([ ['sort_order', 'asc'], ['date', 'desc'] ])
```

Comment: The question is about sorting an existing collection, not how to build a DB query.

Comment: My bad. Updated btw

Comment: @LimKeanPhang  thanks for the follow up but out of the box, the sortBy method doesn’t accept an array. Is there a custom method alongside this answer that will allow this to work?